# Show me duplicated Addresses pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two columns in my csv (Address of New Home and Cancelled `Can` in the csv). If any Address is cancelled, under `Can` True has to be written but sometimes the end user forget to write True and the same Address appears twice. I want Python to ***tell me***(not remove) the Addresses that appear twice without the first one being cancelled out.

Example:

```
Date_Booked         Address of New Home                       Can 

01/07/2017         1234 SO Drive                             True
02/14/2017         4321 Python Court
03/17/2017         1234 SO Drive
03/23/2017         4321 Python Court
```

As you can view from the above example, 1234 SO Drive was cancelled and True was written, this is what we want but 4321 Python Court was cancelled that is why it was written twice but since it does not say True under the Cancelled it will show up twice in our csv and cause all sorts of issues.

```
import pandas as pd

first = pd.read_csv('Z:PCR.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(first)

non_cancelled = df['Can'].apply(lambda x: x != 'True')

dup_addresses = non_cancelled.groupby('Address of New Home').filter(lambda x: len (x) > 1)
if not dup_addresses.empty:
    raise Exception ('Same address written twice without cancellation')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 404, in    pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8543)
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

dup_addresses = non_cancelled.groupby('Address of New Home').filter(lambda x: len (x) > 1)
KeyError: 'Address of New Home'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should update your `Can` column by keeping the `True` that is already there an updating with ones that were missed.

```
can = df.duplicated(subset=['Address of New Home'], keep='last')
df['Can'] = df.Can.combine_first(can.where(can, ''))
print(df)

  Date_Booked Address of New Home   Can
0  01/07/2017       1234 SO Drive  True
1  02/14/2017   4321 Python Court  True
2  03/17/2017       1234 SO Drive      
3  03/23/2017   4321 Python Court
```

---

Per request

```
can = df.duplicated(subset=['Address of New Home'], keep='last')
df['Can'] = df.Can.combine_first(pd.Series(np.where(can, 'Missed', ''), df.index))
print(df)

  Date_Booked Address of New Home     Can
0  01/07/2017       1234 SO Drive    True
1  02/14/2017   4321 Python Court  Missed
2  03/17/2017       1234 SO Drive        
3  03/23/2017   4321 Python Court
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway instead of updating them with `True` I can update them with `End User Missed` please.

Comment: @JakeWagner yes, sorry.  numpy's where is more convenient in this case.  The syntax is cleaner.  We could use pandas still but it's a tad uglier.  Keep in mind, we could think of many ways to solve this.  It was understanding what you needed that was most challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Your column is Address_of_New_Home, not Address of New Home.  Just forgot the underscores

Comment: Sorry wrote it with underscore since used to programming, my apologies. It should be `Address of New Home`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement:

```
non_cancelled = df['Can'].apply(lambda x: x != 'True')
```

When you apply this argument, you are applying to to the series df['Can'], so the method returns a series, not the full DataFrame. To illustrate, here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(0,5), 'b': np.arange(5,10), 'c': np.arange(10,15)})
print(df)
```

The output is this

```
   a  b  c
0  0  5  10
1  1  6  11
2  2  7  12
3  3  8  13
4  4  9  14
```

But when I do this:

```
a = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x*20)
print(a)
```

I get:

```
0     0
1    20
2    40
3    60
4    80
```

To do what you would like to do, try doing this instead:

```
non_cancelled = df[df['Can'] != True]
```

This gives us all rows in the DataFrame where the condition (df['Can'] != True) returns as True